# How to display related custom object in VF using wrapper class according to the user input

Tags: soql, pageblocktable, wrapper-class

```
 Public class Patients
    {
        Public Integer pID{get;set;}
        Public Date sDate{get;set;}
        Public Date eDate{get;set;}
        Public List<wrapPatientInfo> listOfPatients {get;set;}  
        Public List<Patients__c> Pat {get;set;}
        Public List<Treatment_Type__c> TT {get;set;}

            Public Patients()
            {
            if(listOfPatients == null) {
            listOfPatients = new List<wrapPatientInfo>();
            for (Patients__c p: [select Name, pID__c from Patients__c]){
            listOfPatients.add(new wrapPatientInfo(p));} 
            }

        }
            Public void pSearch(){

            //Pat= [select Name from Patients__c where pID__c=:pID];
            // not able to query the table and display it using wrapper class 

            }

            Public class wrapPatientInfo{
                Public Boolean validate {get;set;}
                Public Patients__c Pat {get;set;}
                Public Treatment_Type__c TT {get;set;}

            public wrapPatientInfo(Patients__c p) {
                    Pat =p;
                // Pat = new Patients__c();
                  //TT = new Treatment_Type__c();
                  validate = false;
                  //wrapPatientInfo wp= new wrapPatientInfo();
                }
        }
    }
```

Visualforce Page --------

```
<apex:page controller="Patients">
      <apex:form >
            <apex:pageblock >

                Enter Patient UID : <apex:inputText value="{!pID}"/><br/>
                Enter Patient Start Date : <apex:inputText value="{!sDate}"/><br/>
                Enter Patient End Date : <apex:inputText value="{!eDate}"/><br/>
                <apex:commandbutton value="Search" action="{!pSearch}"/>

                <apex:pageblockSection title="All Patients" collapsible="false" columns="3">
                <apex:pageblockTable value="{!listOfPatients}" var="lp">
                <apex:column >
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!lp.validate}"/>
                 </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!lp.pat.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!lp.pat.pID__c}"/>

                </apex:pageblockTable>
                </apex:pageblockSection>
            </apex:pageblock>
        </apex:form> 
    </apex:page>
```

Comment: Is pID__c Number or Text field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created on my own org custom object patient with Text field pId__c and following code is working for me.

```
Public class Patients {
Public String pID{get;set;}
Public Date sDate{get;set;}
Public Date eDate{get;set;}
Public List<wrapPatientInfo> listOfPatients {get;set;}  
Public List<Patients__c> Pat {get;set;}
Public List<Treatment_Type__c> TT {get;set;}

Public Patients() {
    if(listOfPatients == null) {
    listOfPatients = new List<wrapPatientInfo>();
    for (Patients__c p: [select Name, pID__c from Patients__c]){
        listOfPatients.add(new wrapPatientInfo(p));} 
    }
}

Public void pSearch(){

    Pat= [select Name, pID__c  from Patients__c where pID__c=:pID];

    listOfPatients = new List<wrapPatientInfo>();
    for (Patients__c p: Pat){
        listOfPatients.add(new wrapPatientInfo(p));
    } 
}

Public class wrapPatientInfo{
    Public Boolean validate {get;set;}
    Public Patients__c Pat {get;set;}
    Public Treatment_Type__c TT {get;set;}

    public wrapPatientInfo(Patients__c p) {
        Pat =p;
        validate = false;
    }
}
}
```

=======

Update 10/16/2015.

Updated field type to Number. Added Treatment Types table.

```
<apex:page controller="Patients">
  <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock >

            Enter Patient UID : <apex:inputText value="{!pID}"/><br/>
            Enter Patient Start Date : <apex:inputText value="{!sDate}"/><br/>
            Enter Patient End Date : <apex:inputText value="{!eDate}"/><br/>
            <apex:commandbutton value="Search" action="{!pSearch}"/>

            <apex:pageblockSection title="All Patients" collapsible="false" columns="3">
            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!listOfPatients}" var="lp">
            {!pID}
            <apex:column >
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!lp.validate}"/>
             </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!lp.pat.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!lp.pat.pId__c}"/>

            </apex:pageblockTable>

            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!tt}" var="t">
            <apex:column value="{!t.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!t.Patients__r.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!t.Patients__r.pId__c}"/>
            </apex:pageblockTable>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

and controller

```
Public class Patients {
    Public Integer pID{get;set;}
    Public Date sDate{get;set;}
    Public Date eDate{get;set;}
    Public List<wrapPatientInfo> listOfPatients {get;set;}  
    Public List<Patients__c> Pat {get;set;}
    Public List<Treatment_Type__c> TT {get;set;}

    Public Patients() {
        if(listOfPatients == null) {
        listOfPatients = new List<wrapPatientInfo>();
        for (Patients__c p: [select Name, pID__c from Patients__c]){
            listOfPatients.add(new wrapPatientInfo(p));} 
        }
        TT = [ SELECT Name, Patients__r.Name, Patients__r.pID__c FROM Treatment_Type__c ];
    }

    Public void pSearch(){

        Pat= [select Name, pID__c  from Patients__c where pID__c=:pID];

        listOfPatients = new List<wrapPatientInfo>();
        for (Patients__c p: Pat){
            listOfPatients.add(new wrapPatientInfo(p));
        } 
        TT = [ SELECT Name, Patients__r.Name, Patients__r.pID__c FROM Treatment_Type__c where Patients__r.pID__c=:pID];
    }

    Public class wrapPatientInfo{
        Public Boolean validate {get;set;}
        Public Patients__c Pat {get;set;}
        Public Treatment_Type__c TT {get;set;}

        public wrapPatientInfo(Patients__c p) {
            Pat =p;
            validate = false;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Another screenshot showing search]

Comment: @Patlalus Oh yes , when i changed the datatype it works! but whats the logic behind it ? Could you please explain.
I want to actually display fields from related table Treatment_Type__c .[Select Name , pId, (Select Name fromTreatment_Type__r )from Patients__c]How do i add it to wrapper class and display on VF. Thanks a ton

Comment: @StayKool, so could you please tell me what is intended datatype of the field? and what it stands for, what is the meaning of that field?
What is relationship between Treatment Type and Patient? 
Is that one to many or many to one or many to many?
I mean, is there one Patient and many Treatment types related to patient, or many patients related to given treatment type or many patients can be related to many treatment types?

Comment: pID is patient Id through which we search for a particular patient in a vf page(taking this as a input parameter). The datatype is Integer. Patient and Treatment type is Master detail relationship, where one patient can have one or more Treatment types. i hope its clear.

Comment: If one patient may have many Treatment Types, are you going to display all of them in one row? I would suggest to query for Treatment Types and display one TT per row. I will update my code.

Comment: Please take a look at updated code.

Comment: I did not understand: TT = [ SELECT Name, Patients__r.Name, Patients__r.pID__c FROM Treatment_Type__c where Patients__r.pID__c=:pID];

Plus its throwing some error.

Error: Compile Error: Didn't understand relationship 'Patients__r' in field path.

Comment: I did not understand: TT = [ SELECT Name, Patients__r.Name, Patients__r.pID__c FROM Treatment_Type__c where Patients__r.pID__c=:pID];

Plus its throwing some error.

Error: Compile Error: Didn't understand relationship 'Patients__r' in field path.
how can i display both patients and tt  in one table as i wanted to calculate the amount for each selected patient  the total treatment amount . it has a seperate calculate button. Hope i am not troubling u

Comment: Patients__r is name of master relationship on Treatment Type. If you have named it in a different way (Patient__r) then you have to include your master relationship name.
If you want to have total treatment amount you need to make an aggregate query like this:
[ SELECT Sum(Amount__c), Patients__r.Name, Patients__r.pID__c FROM Treatment_Type__c where Patients__r.pID__c=:pID group by Patients__r.pID__c, Patients__r.Name]

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Thanks and it worked!!

Comment: I'm glad my solution worked for you